# Pandas dataframe sum value with the above value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is composed only of a column containing scores, the first value is the starting one, e.g. 100, after which the trend of the score is stored in the column, e.g. +10 and in the next row -30 etc., what I would like to have is a column where you only have the starting score and then the already formatted values e.g.:
`100 110 80`
etc.

so i have df like that's:

`12 1 8 -1`

and i want
 `12 13 21 20`

Comment: take a look at the cumsum function

Comment: e.g. `import pandas as pd`

`df = pd.DataFrame({'Score': [12, 1, 8, -1]})`

`df.cumsum()`

Comment: Ciao  Matteo, please have a look at [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Mark is right, we can use cumsum in this scenario like this:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([12,1,8,-1])
def g(df):
    df['new'] = df.iloc[0] + df.iloc[1:].cumsum()
    return df[['new']]

df = g(df.copy())
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  new
0 NaN
1  13.0
2  21.0
3  20.0
```